# Python (maximum recursion depth exceeded) vs Haskell (finds out the answer)

Tags: python, haskell, recursion

So i started to learn Haskell a little. After getting to the recursive definitions, i coded the factorial definition as:

```
let fac n = if n==0 then 1 else n*fac(n-1)
```

(Pretty different way of coding it, i know :) )

I think this is the same as python definition:

```
def fac(n): 
  if n==0:
    return 1
  else:
    return n*fac(n-1)
```

My question is about the max recursion depth error that python throws. Although the 2 functions are coded in same way, what is it that makes the python to throw an error and haskell to calculate the result when n=1000?

Comment: Python has a maximum recursion depth, defaulting to 1000. Haskell doesn't. It's a matter of design philosophy; 1000 is enough for most practical recursive algorithms in Python, but Haskell emphasizes recursion much more.

Comment: i thought it was about the way they exhaust the processor, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not tail-recursive, so Haskell is going to crash eventually, too.

```
fac :: Int -> Int
fac n = if n == 0 then 1 else n*fac(n-1)
```

(the answer doesn't fit in Int, just making it deliver the crash sooner)

Leave the question of correctness, just run `fac 10000000` and see it crash with stack overflow.

Here's the tail-recursive one:

```
fac :: Int -> Int
fac n = g 1 n where g a n = if n == 0 then a else g (a*n) (n-1)
```

doesn't crash. (but not the right answer either, because Int is used)

(Also, as is correctly pointed out in comments, if we leave the function with the default `Integer -> Integer` type, it will use integers that are not bound by CPU architecture. But since then the computation will take much longer, it will take much longer to satisfy ourselves that the non-tail-recursive eventually crashes.)

In comments here there are complaints that `g` is lazy in `a`. Whereas in general it is a concern, it was not the point here, and in this particular case there is no difference:

```
> ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl a.hs > a.dump.lazy
...
Rec {
Main.$wg [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int#
[GblId, Arity=2, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType LL]
Main.$wg =
  \ (ww_s11J :: GHC.Prim.Int#) (ww1_s11N :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case ww1_s11N of wild_Xn {
      __DEFAULT ->
        Main.$wg (GHC.Prim.*# ww_s11J wild_Xn) (GHC.Prim.-# wild_Xn 1);
      0 -> ww_s11J
    }
end Rec }
```

Now, the same, but making `g` strict in `a`:

```
  fac :: Int -> Int
  fac n = g 1 n where
    g !a n = if n == 0 then a else g (a*n) (n-1)
> ghc -O2 -XBangPatterns -ddump-simpl a.hs > a.dump.eager
...
Rec {
Main.$wg [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int#
[GblId, Arity=2, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType LL]
Main.$wg =
  \ (ww_s11P :: GHC.Prim.Int#) (ww1_s11T :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case ww1_s11T of wild_Xs {
      __DEFAULT ->
        Main.$wg (GHC.Prim.*# ww_s11P wild_Xs) (GHC.Prim.-# wild_Xs 1);
      0 -> ww_s11P
    }
end Rec }
```

Evidently, the optimizer can see the only return value of `g` is `a`, so there is no gain from making it lazy is `a`.

Comment: To add, to get the correct behaviour the type should be `Integer -> Integer` as `Int`'s are bounded by the system while `Integer` is an arbitrarily sized integer.

Comment: Wouldn't this still crash in an overflow of thunks, since g is lazy in a? You basically suggest `foldl` in place of `foldr`, when you really need `foldl'`.

Comment: @ollanta of course. The question was about recursion, so I explained the difference the tail recursion makes. Also, a good question would be: will it crash, or start reducing thunks when going low on memory (before crashing OutOfMemory)?

Comment: @jozefg sure. I had `Integer -> Integer` first, but then even to crash the non-tail-recursive it takes ages. I'll add this point.

Comment: @ollanta btw, in this case it worked out that g is not lazy in `a` and produces identical code for `g !a n = ...`.

Comment: @SassaNF Huh? `g` seems lazy on `a` to me.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues yes, the definition is lazy, but the generated code doesn't have to be, and it isn't. In particular, strictness analysis can show the only return value from `g` is the value of `a`, so there is no gain from making it lazy. Comparing the code dump for `g a n` and `g !a n` shows no difference - so this analysis must be occurring in this case.

Comment: @SassaNF well, maybe I'm just confusing the OP unnecessarily, but since recursion (especially tail-recursion) is so different in strict languages, I think it would be a bit misleading if it wasn't mentioned. Also, in dumped the core in 7.6.3 and I do see a difference...

Comment: @SassaNF ah, you compiled with optimization, that would be the difference :)

Comment: @SassaNF True if the `-O2` flag is used, otherwise the generated code is different, and blows up with a stack overflow for high values of `n`.